# Pause and resume animation in the same keyframe

Tags: ios, scenekit

Is it possible to pause animation of SCNNode (animaton with model from .dae collada) and then resume in the same keyframe which it was paused?

Comment: What type of animation is it?

Comment: Pausing it like you would normally pause an animation on iOS didn't work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your first question, it's walk animation made in Blender.

Pausing works good but when I want to resume, the animation starts from the beginning not from the keyframe which was paused.

Comment: And you are doing [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html)?

Comment: I saw it but I don't know how to use it with CAAnimation, simple changing CALayer to CAAniamtion doesn't work

Comment: How are you pausing it? Using the `paused` property of `SCNNode` should work. You might also have to fiddle with the animation's time base — if it's based on scene time, scene time will continue while the node is paused, so it'll resume at a different (relative) time.

Answer (score 0):

Will using the `isPaused` property on the `SCNNode` work for your needs?

Example:

`self.childNode.isPaused = true`